# $ is undefined (JSON)

Tags: json

I'm trying to use JSON for the first and I use the code:

```
var url = 'http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=Vancouver&flags=J&count=10&lang=en&appid=' + myAppId + '&callback=?';


$.getJSON(url, function(data){
console.dir(data);
});
```

but I get on IE8 the error :
'$' is undefined

what am I doing wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use jQuery and the script include is missing. 
Include the URL for jQuery.js before using the $.

Try to place something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before the getJSON

Comment: thanks. this error no longer appears but nothing happens. how could I make this code work?

Answer (score 2):

$ is provided by a couple JavaScript libraries, the most common of which is jQuery.

If you're not including jQuery in your page, that's likely your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not including JQuery before making this call?

Answer (score 0):

the $ symbol is used by JQuery. Do you have the script for jquery included in the web app before you are using it ?

add this at the top of the offending page.

```
<script src="{Change this to the path to your jquery.js file}"></script>
```